# How to convert Array to Lists instead for Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error in my Android Studio.Previous version of Firebase SDK supported this but the new SDK is not supporting it.Please help to solve this.

```
02-11 23:38:47.647  14487-14487/com.potenza_pvt_ltd.AAPS E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.potenza_pvt_ltd.AAPS, PID: 14487
        Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:com.cyngn.hexo, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Converting to Arrays is not supported, please use Listsinstead
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zzaC(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzd(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                at com.potenza_pvt_ltd.AAPS.ExitReceipt$7.onChildAdded(ExitReceipt.java:322)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaer.zza(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is my POJO class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class TariffDetails {

    private String vehicle_type;
    private String key;
    private String total_slab_hrs;
    private String no_of_slab_hrs;
    private String inc_dur_hrs;
    private String tariff;
    private String code;
    private int[][] arr;

    public TariffDetails() {

            /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
    }
    public TariffDetails(String a){

    }
    @JsonProperty("Key")
    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("Key")
    public void setKey(String key){
        this.key=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("vtype")
    public String getVehicle_type(){
        return vehicle_type;
    }
    @JsonProperty("vtype")
    public void setVehicle_type(String key){
        this.vehicle_type=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("total_slab_hrs")
    public String getTotal_slab_hrs(){
        return total_slab_hrs;
    }
    @JsonProperty("total_slab_hrs")
    public void setTotal_slab_hrs(String key){
        this.total_slab_hrs=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("no_of_slab_hrs")
    public String getNo_of_slab_hrs(){
        return no_of_slab_hrs;
    }
    @JsonProperty("no_of_slab_hrs")
    public void setNo_of_slab_hrs(String key){
        this.no_of_slab_hrs=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("inc_dur_hrs")
    public String getInc_dur_hrs(){
        return inc_dur_hrs;
    }
    @JsonProperty("inc_dur_hrs")
    public void setInc_dur_hrs(String key){
        this.inc_dur_hrs=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("inslipp_tariff")
    public String getInslip_tariff(){
        return tariff;
    }
    @JsonProperty("inslipp_tariff")
    public void setInslip_tariff(String key){
        this.tariff=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public void setCode(String key){
        this.code=key;
    }
    @JsonProperty("arr")
    public int[][] getArr(){
        return arr;
    }
    @JsonProperty("arr")
    public void setArr(int[][] a){
        this.arr=a;
    }


}
```

this is my main part where i call it.

```
Query queryRef1 = reference.child("users").child("Tariff_Details").orderByChild("vtype").equalTo(code_value_1);
            queryRef1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d("value of get data", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    TariffDetails post = dataSnapshot.getValue(TariffDetails.class);
                    tar_arr = post.getArr();
                    for (int i = 0; i < tar_arr.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            Log.d("ARR", String.valueOf(tar_arr[i][j]));
                            arr.add(tar_arr[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                    if(tar_arr!=null){
                        adapter = new CustomGrid(getApplicationContext(), tar_arr,code_value_1);
                        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You Clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    f[0] =1;
                    pb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    linear_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d("value of get data", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    TariffDetails post = dataSnapshot.getValue(TariffDetails.class);
                    tar_arr = post.getArr();
                    for (int i = 0; i < tar_arr.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            Log.d("ARR", String.valueOf(tar_arr[i][j]));
                            arr.add(tar_arr[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                    if(tar_arr!=null){
                        adapter = new CustomGrid(getApplicationContext(), tar_arr,code_value_1);
                        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    tar_arr = null;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: you should check this too: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Link is not working @brykneval.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay i have uploaded the code please check and let me know the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Simple use `Arrays.asList(yourArray)` to have it as list.

Comment: you can also use `yourArray.asList()`